# Talend Java heap space on large json files

Tags: java, json, talend

I am trying to extract data from a large JSON file (700Mb) and I have a Java heap space exception during the job.
I already try to improve my JVM arguments (I have 16GB of RAM)  with theses, :

```
-Xms512M
-Xmx8192M
```

For now i have a simple job for test the loading of the file like these :

[image]

I tried with JSONPath to only take the first data in my array like this but it didn't work :
`"$.[:1]fields[:1]"`

Do you have ideas to improve the performance of my job or parse data in a smart way ?

Comment: You need to show which library you are using to parse the Json file. Ideally for large files you want to use a streaming parser; if you have a parser that loads in the entire file into memory then that could cause problems, especially if it is loading the content into a single growable byte array.

Comment: "A smart way" in case of 1 and more GB file is to use stream/token/event oriented parsing. https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-streaming-api. You also could take a look at a small, GC-free lib https://github.com/anatolygudkov/green-jelly

Comment: I use the default parser of tFileInputJson